# Are your delts supposed to cover the horizontal surfaces of your shoulders too?

Tags: shoulders

Are your delts – or anything else, for that matter – supposed to cover your shoulders* too? I'm generally fit, though admittedly my delts are my weak spot. But the thing is I don't have any muscle tissue **on** my shoulders altogether, it's just bony spikes with skin stretched over it. Recently I took up doing butterfly raises to specificaly boost my front and middle delts, but I see gains going only sideways, there's still no muscle at all on the upper surfaces. Why am I concerned about it in the first place? Well, it's almost embarrassing to tell, but every time a girl ventures to lean her head on my shoulder, it makes a terribly awkward experience for me (and a terribly uncomfortable experience  for her)!

**as in "the parts of the human torso forming a relatively horizontal surface running away from the neck"*

Comment: Not...really. Most of that structure in the area is tendons and ligaments which won't grow.

Comment: @JohnP but what is one supposed to do? To grow their neck to cover those spikes? How feasible is that (not really, I think)?

Comment: You can grow the sternocleidomastoid, the traps, the delts, but in the end you just might have bony shoulders. It all depends on your own structure how much will be covered.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I've understood you correctly and I'm afraid that there is really not a lot that you can do about it! I think that my shoulders are some of my better features but I still have maybe a one inch stretch between where my delts attach to the skeleton and before the traps offer some bulk where it is hard to the touch!

[image: illustration of delt attachments, courtesy of https://www.yourhousefitness.com/blog/muscle-breakdown-anterior-deltoid]

To address your underlying fear, the shoulder is a very mobile joint and it's not difficult to turn it such that someone's head is kept away from that small bony / hard section - for example, you can raise your arm slightly and embrace someone so that they are pulled into the anterior delt, if you're lying down then somewhere between anterior delt and pec offers a comfy spot, if someone insists on sitting next to you and leaning their head on your shoulder then I can't imagine that they would be adverse to you putting your arm around them and that should offer them a very comfortable resting place (somewhat similar to lying down)!